# How to replace color with image in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, node-canvas

As I mentioned in the title, how do I replace a color with a image in NodeJS? Like a green screen

Comment: Hey mate i never used it but on first search i found this https://www.npmjs.com/package/replace-color, maybe try it out? :)

Comment: It replaces it with color but I want it to replace it with the image.

Comment: Ohh :D there are examples about green screen. Let's keep searching.

Comment: Maybe this https://github.com/lovell/sharp or this https://medium.com/@rossbulat/image-processing-in-nodejs-with-jimp-174f39336153

Comment: Bdw I'm not sure if nodejs is the best option for playing around with images. Maybe send a request to php or python server and do everything there?

Comment: I will try. Thanks for your help Halil kardeşim :D

Answer (score 1):

The replace colour package using Jimp does exactly that

https://www.npmjs.com/package/replace-color

Answer (score 0):

I would start out by saying that node is probably not the best thing to do this in. But I usually use https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/ for all my image processing in node.